# bind9 DNS server and virtualhosts apache2: getting to work multiple virtualhost like foo.myenterprise.com

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, virtualhost, bind, apache2

My goal is to host various sites (local virtualhosts) on my apache webserver in the LAN of my enterprise (Debian 9 server).

So that:

- openproject.myenterprise.local => /opt/openproject
- wiki.myenterprise.local => /var/www/location/wiki
- etc.

I configured virtualhosts on my apache2 webserver with

- /etc/apache2/sites-available/openproject.conf `ServerName openproject.myenterprise.local`
- /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-main-static-site.conf `ServerName vmDebDevSrv1.myenterprise.local ServerAlias salado.myenterprise.local`
- /etc/apache2/sites-available/001-wiki.conf `ServerName  wiki.myenterprise.local`

Now its working with a local configuration in `/etc/hosts`

```
172.16.12.171 openproject.myenterprise.local
172.16.12.171 wiki.myenterprise.local
```

When I add the **DNS resolution with bind9** it doesn't work anymore. I guess it is because of the incapacity of my server to relay the FQDN I use.

- When I ping or put the url into my browser `wiki` it works but gives me the main directory of my webserver not the wiki virtualhost

**Edit: ping wiki** gives me:

```
ws1: ~$ ping wiki
PING ns1.myenterprise.local (172.16.10.174): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.16.10.174: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.282 ms
^C--- ns1.myenterprise.local ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.282/0.325/0.368/0.043 ms
```

**/edit**

- When I ping wiki.myenterprise.local it doesn't work `ping: unknown host`, **Edit:** nslookup works with FQDN **/Edit**

**My /etc/resolv.conf**

```
domain myenterprise.local
search myenterprise.local
nameserver 172.16.12.174
nameserver 172.16.12.1
nameserver ...
```

**/etc/bind/db.myenterprise.local**

```
$TTL|   604800
@|      IN|     SOA|    ns1.myenterprise.local. root.vmDebDevSrv1.myenterprise.local. (
|       |       |       20181129|       ; Serial
|       |       |        604800||       ; Refresh
|       |       |         86400||       ; Retry
|       |       |       2419200||       ; Expire
|       |       |        604800 )|      ; Negative Cache TTL

;Name server information
@|      IN|     NS|     ns1.myenterprise.local.

;IP Address of Domain Name Server(DNS) setted on line above
ns1|    IN|     A|      172.16.12.174

;CNAME Records
vmDebDevSrv1|   IN|     CNAME|  ns1.myenterprise.local.
wiki|   IN|     CNAME|  vmDebDevSrv1.myenterprise.local.
openproject|    IN|     CNAME|  vmDebDevSrv1.myenterprise.local.

;tried too with 
;wiki|   IN|     A  172.16.12.174
;openproject|   IN|     A  172.16.12.174
```

**What Am I missing?!!!** I thought the path would be `short-name=>DNS=>FQDN=>Apache2=>well page returned`

So I guess its impossible to get

Comment: Do you have a `search domain` in your `/etc/resolv.conf` ? That can affect the `hostname` -> `hostname.domain` conversion

Comment: @ivanivan yes thx, edited the question.

Comment: Lot's of info on your apache config. What about details on your DNS config and resolution?

Comment: @Tom edited thx, tell me if there is a need for more...

Comment: if I read it correctly, the configuration with the CNAME will default to the default site, dir you reload the bind9 server after trying with the IN records (and removed the CNAME?)? after you do the change check with dig what you will get fir wiki/openproject.

Comment: You have two name servers. What server is using IP address 172.16.12.1? This might be causing some of the problems you're facing.

Comment: @Tom 172.16.12.1 is the internet router direction so if my DNS server is down the network still works...

Comment: But can your internet router also resolve those `myenterprise.local` names?

Comment: @Tom nope, having to duplicate these entries is not in my goal, maybe I'm wrong with my practices in which case you could point me out some documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I ping or put the url into my browser wiki it works but gives me the main directory of my webserver not the wiki virtualhost.

When you only enter `wiki` in your browser window, I would say that even though the OS adds the search domains when trying to perform a DNS lookup, the `Host` header sent in the HTTP request is just what you've put in the browser window, i.e. `Host: wiki`. To make that work, put in a `ServerAlias wiki` in your Apache configuration.

> When I ping wiki.myenterprise.local it doesn't work.

Can you paste the output of your ping commands? Some troubleshooting steps to consider:

- Can you resolve your FQDNs? Please provide proof that you can.
- Can you resolve using only the host names, i.e. is the search domain correctly being applied to your DNS queries? Please provide proof that you can.
- Do they all resolve to the correct IP address(es)? Please provide proof.
- If **ping** doesn't work, check your routing and firewall rules.

Comment: Thx! `nslookup wiki.myenterprise.local
Server:         172.16.10.174
Address:        172.16.10.174#53
wiki.myenterprise.local     canonical name = vmDebDevSrv1.myenterprise.local.
vmDebDevSrv1.myenterprise.local     canonical name = ns1.myenterprise.local.
Name:   ns1.myenterprise.local
Address: 172.16.10.174`

Comment: `ping wiki.myenterprise.local
ping: unknown host`

Comment: `ping wiki
    PING ns1.myenterprise.local (172.16.10.174): 56 data bytes
    64 bytes from 172.16.10.174: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.282 ms
    64 bytes from 172.16.10.174: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.368 ms
    ^C--- ns1.myenterprise.local ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
    round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.282/0.325/0.368/0.043 ms`

Comment: `put in a ServerAlias wiki` did the trick!